# Javascript can't see an object id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox

I want to perform some actions over my objects via Javascript, but I don't get why my script isn't binding objects. Any suggestions?

**My _index.html file:**

```
<table>
  <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
    <tr class='tasks' id="task_<%= task.id %>">

      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class='check' data-id="<%= task.id %>" >
      </td>

    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

**Here's the script in application.js:**

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
    $('.check').on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $("task_<%= task.id %>").fadeOut();
    }
  });
})
```

It does nothing. However, when I go with `$(.tasks)` all of objects fade out along.

Comment: $("task_<%= task.id %>") this is not right usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your javascript to:

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
    $('.check').on('change', function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        # get `id` from attribute
        $("#task_" + id).fadeOut();
      }
    });
 })
```

You can't use `erb` interpolation in `application.js`, not in all case, but in this. Because `application.js` script works on client-side.

[`Adding JavaScript to Rails`](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html)

Comment: I think It should be like that $("#task_" + id).fadeOut();